# How can I get the list of github users with email and full name by filtering with the number of followers and locations?

Tags: api, github, github-api

I tried to get the list of Github users by filtering with the number of followers and locations.
So I tried with several methods by referring to the GitHub API documents, but I was not able to find the solution yet.
https://developer.github.com/v3/users/
All the results look like below.

```json
{
    "login": "octocat",
    "id": 1,
    "node_id": "MDQ6VXNlcjE=",
    "avatar_url": "https://github.com/images/error/octocat_happy.gif",
    "gravatar_id": "",
    "url": "https://api.github.com/users/octocat",
    "html_url": "https://github.com/octocat",
    "followers_url": "https://api.github.com/users/octocat/followers",
    "following_url": "https://api.github.com/users/octocat/following{/other_user}",
    "gists_url": "https://api.github.com/users/octocat/gists{/gist_id}",
    "starred_url": "https://api.github.com/users/octocat/starred{/owner}{/repo}",
    "subscriptions_url": "https://api.github.com/users/octocat/subscriptions",
    "organizations_url": "https://api.github.com/users/octocat/orgs",
    "repos_url": "https://api.github.com/users/octocat/repos",
    "events_url": "https://api.github.com/users/octocat/events{/privacy}",
    "received_events_url": "https://api.github.com/users/octocat/received_events",
    "type": "User",
    "site_admin": false
  }
```

But I'd like to get the results like below.

```json
{
  "login": "octocat",
  "id": 1,
  "node_id": "MDQ6VXNlcjE=",
  "avatar_url": "https://github.com/images/error/octocat_happy.gif",
  "gravatar_id": "",
  "url": "https://api.github.com/users/octocat",
  "html_url": "https://github.com/octocat",
  "followers_url": "https://api.github.com/users/octocat/followers",
  "following_url": "https://api.github.com/users/octocat/following{/other_user}",
  "gists_url": "https://api.github.com/users/octocat/gists{/gist_id}",
  "starred_url": "https://api.github.com/users/octocat/starred{/owner}{/repo}",
  "subscriptions_url": "https://api.github.com/users/octocat/subscriptions",
  "organizations_url": "https://api.github.com/users/octocat/orgs",
  "repos_url": "https://api.github.com/users/octocat/repos",
  "events_url": "https://api.github.com/users/octocat/events{/privacy}",
  "received_events_url": "https://api.github.com/users/octocat/received_events",
  "type": "User",
  "site_admin": false,
  "name": "monalisa octocat",
  "company": "GitHub",
  "blog": "https://github.com/blog",
  "location": "San Francisco",
  "email": "octocat@github.com",
  "hireable": false,
  "bio": "There once was...",
  "twitter_username": "monatheoctocat",
  "public_repos": 2,
  "public_gists": 1,
  "followers": 20,
  "following": 0,
  "created_at": "2008-01-14T04:33:35Z",
  "updated_at": "2008-01-14T04:33:35Z"
}
```

I want to get a list of such user information by filtering with location and the number of followers.
If you have any solution to that problem then please don't hesitate to help me.

Thanks.

Comment: Did you get the results?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Github Search API](https://developer.github.com/v3/search/#search-users) to filter with the [`location`](https://docs.github.com/en/free-pro-team@latest/github/searching-for-information-on-github/searching-users#search-by-location) to get the location and [`followers`](https://docs.github.com/en/free-pro-team@latest/github/searching-for-information-on-github/searching-users#search-by-number-of-followers) to filter the follower count. The search query would be :

```
location:iceland followers:>=100
```

An example : https://api.github.com/search/users?q=location:iceland%20followers:%3E=100

Using [GraphQL API](https://developer.github.com/v4/) it would be :

```graphql
{
  search(type: USER, query: "location:iceland followers:>=100",first:100){
        userCount
    nodes {
      ...on User {
        login
        bio
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But with this answer, I am not able to get the user name and email address of the users.